# Jquery Ajax request to an static html resource in Nginx causes a "405 Not Allowed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nginx, cors

I have an Nginx with a simple index.thml running within a Docker. Everything works fine if I call it from a browser with http://localhost:8979/index.html, but when I call it from JQuery Ajax in another server (https://localhost:8447/) like this

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8979/index.html",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#myDiv").html(data);
            }
        });
```

I obtain this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8979/index.html' from origin 'https://localhost:8447' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My Nginx configuration is this:

```
server { 
 listen 80;
 location / {
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type'; 
 }
}
```

I can see in Devtools this two requests:

```
General
    Request URL: http://localhost:8979/index.html
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
    Accept: */*
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Referer
    sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="86", "\"Not\\A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="86"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    User-Agent: M
```

```
General
    Request URL: http://localhost:8979/index.html
    Request Method: OPTIONS
    Status Code: 405 Not Allowed
    Remote Address: [::1]:8979
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response Headers
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 559
    Content-Type: text/html
    Date: Thu, 12 Nov 2020 17:54:48 GMT
    Server: nginx/1.19.4
Request Headers
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin
    Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: localhost:8979
    Origin: https://localhost:8447
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 1....
```

My Docker file:

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./src/static /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Is the problem in the Ajax request or is a configuration issue?

Comment: Why there is two equal prefix locations in your nginx config? Who wrote that? The second one is useless and would never be reached, those headers would never be set. Move `add_header` directives to the first one and remove the second.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I removed it, but the problem remains the same (post edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
map $request_method $options_content_type {
    OPTIONS    "text/plain";
}
map $request_method $options_content_length {
    OPTIONS    0;
}
server { 
    listen 80;
    location / {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) { return 204; }
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type'; 
        add_header Content-Type $options_content_type;
        add_header Content-Length $options_content_length;
    }
}
```

Beware! You are declaring GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE and PUT as allowed HTTP methods, but in fact nothing except GET (and now OPTIONS) will work with this configuration. Do you really need all the other methods?

Comment: The problem was that conf file was not copied on target folder. Now it works with: ```server { 
 listen 80;
 location / {
   root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
   index  index.html index.htm;
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type'; 
 }
}``` Anyway, I will review those other methods. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel That config won't serve the `OPTIONS` HTTP method giving you 405 Method not allowed response (although it may be not strictly required for the successful AJAX request/response).